# Find the maximum and parent value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I searched many thread but i can't find this solution
I have this Array

```
Array 
( [0] => [1] => Array ( [0] => 2019-01-11T23:30:00CET [1] => -12.6 ) [2] => [3] => Array ( [0] => 2019-01-11T23:20:00CET [1] => -12.5 ) [4] => [5] => Array ( [0] => 2019-01-11T23:10:00CET [1] => -12.6 ) [10] => [11] => Array ( [0] => 2019-01-11T22:40:00CET [1] => -12.4 )
```

I found the path to have the maximum or minimum value ( Column [1] ) from this Array but i need to find the relative Parent

> (example the minimum -12.6 is in the [1][0] as 2019-01-11T22:20:00CET)
>   of this two values that are show in the first column ( Column[0] )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract the second column of your data, then you can use `min()` or `max()` with that array to pick which one you want.  This code then extracts the ones that match using a `foreach()` and `if` to check if it matches (not exactly sure what you want as output, but this should help)...

```
$source = [["2019-01-11T23:30:00CET", -12.6],
    ["2019-01-11T23:20:00CET", -12.5],
    ["2019-01-11T23:10:00CET", -12.6]
];

$extract = min(array_column($source, 1));  // or use max()
$output = [];
foreach ($source as $key => $element) {
    if ( $element[1] == $extract )  {
        // Matches, so add to output
        $output[$key] = $element[0];
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

will give

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-01-11T23:30:00CET
    [2] => 2019-01-11T23:10:00CET
)
```

You could use `array_filter()` to extract the matching rows, but a `foreach()` is enough for a straightforward thing like this (IMHO).

If there is a possibility of blank values or strings in the value column, this may confuse the `min()` as it will consider the values and compare them as strings, to ensure they are all compared as numbers you can add...

```
$values = array_map("floatval", array_column($source, 1));
$extract = min($values);  // or use max()
```

The `array_map("floatval",...` goes through the list and converts them all to float values.

Comment: I really appreciated your advice! I have some problem because i use normally an old 5.3 php, but i installed a new 7.2 php version and work very good. Thank you!

Comment: I found a Problem @nigel. If i had a number example -8.4 and another -9.9 and another -12.6 and a try to find the lowest, the system catch the -9.9. I tried so many things, and I found a solution. Add a 0 to the single number from 1 to 10 (positive and negative numbers). How can i add this feature to this code? Thanks (PS My $source is an array of 150 rows from a csv file)

Comment: I've updated the answer, it makes sure that all values are floats and forces numeric comparison.

Comment: Re-Thank you @nigel. I appreciated so much. All is working

Answer (score 0):

Also, here's a generalized algorithm-sketch for "finding the max in some array", expressed as pseudo-code:

- "Leave quietly" if the array is empty, or throw an exception.
- Otherwise, assume that the first element in the array *is* the biggest one.
- Now, loop through the remaining elements, testing if each one is, in fact, bigger than the "biggest one" that you have so far.  If so, select it as the "biggest."
- When the loop is finished, return your answer.

Now – this is what a geek would call "an *O(n)* algorithm," which is to say that its execution-time will be "on the order of" the number of elements in the array.  Well, if this is a "one-off" requirement, that's fine.  Whereas if what you *actually* want to do is to get "more than one" max-element, sorting the array *(once, then holding on to the sorted result ...)* becomes significantly better, because the sort is going to be *O(log(n))* ... "on the order of *some logarithm of* the number of elements," ... and the subsequent cost of "popping off" elements from that sorted array becomes non-existent.

There are other ways to do it, of course – trees and such - but I've already blathered-on too long here.